# Why the Paperclip cause my WEBrick server collapse frequently?

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Well, I added Paperclip into my project in Rails 3.1 to handle the images and avatars.
I installed the Paperclip as gem.
In gemfile I wrote:

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git',
                 :branch => 'rails3'
```

Well, I actually quite spent some effort and finally get the paperclip working correctly. However, during development, I have found that if I frequently refresh a webpage which has avatars within a short time, the WEBrick could soon collapse and turned down.

The error message is something like:

> Ruby interpreter(CUI) 1.9.2p290 [i386-mingw32] has shut down.

My development environment is:
  Ruby 1.9
  Rails 3.1
  WIN7 32bit

Such frequent collapses really cause inconvenience. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Seems noone answering this problem, in my case I just replace WEBrick with Thin and Passenger